# ruby install fails with rbenv and ruby-build

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I want to install `ruby 2.1.2` in Mint 16 Cinnamon on VirtualBox.

I've installed `rbenv` with `ruby-build` plugin and run `rbenv install 2.1.2`, then failed with this error.

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-build.20140518190910.5012/ruby-2.1.2':
```

`gcc --version` outputs:

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I got same error with `rbenv install 2.1.1` and `2.0.0-p481`.

What can I do to install the ruby with rbenv?

Answer (score 0):

I've forgotten install related libraries.

```
$ sudo aptitude install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

This command solved my problem.